# scrlttr2: how to reduce space between text and footer

Tags: spacing, header-footer, scrlttr2

How do I reduce the spacing between the last line of "regular" text and the footer?

I tried increasing `\footskip`, but instead of moving the footer up, this results in the main text wrapping onto the next page earlier...

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=letter,
      parskip=half, firstfoot=on,]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\setlength{\footskip}{4cm}
\firstfoot{\centering\emph{(please turn)}}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{
      Foobar\\
    }
    \setkomavar{subject}{It won't work!}
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
    \lipsum
    \closing{Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before messing around with `footskip` or KOMA-script-specific pseudo-lengths, I would recommend the class option `enlargefirstpage`. Maybe this already solves your layout problem.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=letter,
      parskip=half, firstfoot=on,enlargefirstpage]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\firstfoot{\centering\emph{(please turn)}}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
%\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}
%\makeatletter
%\@addtoplength{firstfootvpos}{0.5cm}
%\makeatother
\setkomavar{subject}{It won't work!}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{ Foobar\\ XYZ town}
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
 \lipsum
    \closing{Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Please note: if you want to make changes of the letter's layout, you have to do so after the `\LoadLetterOption{...}` statement. Otherwise your changes will be overwritten by the loaded definition.